# When I verify the apple iap receipt (consumable), field in_app we got 2 items. Which one should we verify to update our order status to success?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am implement the IAP and verify the receipt on server side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the application side, you should have the `transaction_id` associated to your purchase. Send this `transaction_id` to your server and check the in_app matching this `transaction_id`.

Be careful: someone could try to always send you the same consumable to abuse your server and get infinite consumables. That's why you have to be sure to take into account each consumable only 1 time on your server.

Comment: As consumable, why the receipt have 2 transactions, can you help explain it?

Comment: You can buy as many consumables as you want. And as you can see, you have 2 different `original_transaction_id` (and 2 `original_purchase_at` as a matter of fact), which means you have 2 different purchases.